# Adding Fourier transform features to data

Tags: classification, regression, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I'm working on some timeseries data which after visualising seems to be periodic(repeating at some interval), So I planned on finding the Fourier transform of the entire and pick the top n amplitudes and frequencies to add them as features to my existing data which has features such as mean averages, exponentially weighted averages and weighted averages. I had found the top 5 amplitudes and frequencies by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEYDBb3XkkY&t=330s) video. Now I'm not sure how do I add this to my dataset as my dataset has roughly around 100K points. Should I add the same observation to all the 100K points?? I need some help to get around this problem. Thanks in advance